# Why is sprockets not finding an asset in my vendors folder even though its in the load path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-5, sprockets

This is the file & folder I am trying to include in my `application.scss`:

```
$ ls
jquery.nouislider.css
$ pwd
myapp/vendor/assets/stylesheets/inspinia/plugins/nouslider
```

I am including it like so:

```
@import "inspinia/plugins/nouslider/*";
```

This is the error I get:

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound - couldn't find file '/app/assets/stylesheets/inspinia/plugins/nouslider'
Checked in these paths: 
  /app/assets/config
  /app/assets/fonts
  /app/assets/images
  /app/assets/javascripts
  /app/assets/stylesheets
  /vendor/assets/javascripts
  /vendor/assets/stylesheets
```

How do I properly include this folder without throwing an error?

**Edit 1**

What's weird is that I have these two files:

```
$ ls
animate.css patterns    plugins     style.css
$ pwd
/vendor/assets/stylesheets/inspinia
```

And I successfully include it like so:

```
 @import "inspinia/style";
 @import "inspinia/animate";
```

So not sure why the above won't work.

**Edit 2**

I finally got it working, kinda.

What I did was moved the file I wanted to the `/inspinia` folder and then renamed it from `jquery.nouislider.css` and rename it to `nouislider.css`.

Then I just imported it like this:

```
@import "inspinia/nouislider";
```

That worked, but I don't know why the normal path and longer file name didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I've stuck with the same problem and found a better approach to import glob.
`@import` works fine only with relative paths. So you can use smth like:

```
@import "../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/inspinia/**/*";
```

Ref to [glob-imports doc](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails#glob-imports)

Answer (score 0):

You should include complete path and try again
Vendor/assets/stylesheets/inspinia/ as it is test or use require or load instead of import